# How to estimate the integeral of an oscillating curve using the Monte-Carlo method (in python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, montecarlo, integral

I am trying to estimate the integral below using the Monte-Carlo method (in python):

[image]

I am using 1000 random points to estimate the integral. Here's my code:

```
N = 1000 #total number of points to be generated

def f(x):
    return x*np.cos(x)

##Points between the x-axis and the curve will be stored in these empty lists.
red_points_x = []
red_points_y = []
blue_points_x = []
blue_points_y = []

##The loop checks if a point is between the x-axis and the curve or not.
i = 0
while i < N:
    x = random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi) 
    y = random.uniform(3.426*np.cos(3.426), 2*np.pi*np.cos(2*np.pi)) 
    if (0<= x <= np.pi and 0<= y <= f(x)) or (np.pi/2 <= x <= 3*np.pi/2 and f(x) <= y <= 0) or (3*np.pi/2 <= x <= 2*np.pi and 0 <= y <= f(x)):
        red_points_x.append(x)  
        red_points_y.append(y)   

    else:
        blue_points_x.append(x)
        blue_points_y.append(y)
    i +=1

area_of_rectangle= (2*np.pi)*(2*np.pi*np.cos(2*np.pi))

area= area_of_rectangle*(len(red_points_x))/N

print(area)
```

Output:

```
7.658813015245341
```

But that's far from 0 (the analytic solution)

Here's a visual representation of the area I am trying to plot:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or missing something in my code? Please help, your help will be much appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: I believe the way you calculate the approximation is slightly wrong.

Looking a the wikipedia definition of the Monte Carlo integration the following definition is made: 
[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration#Example

V corresponds the volume (area in this case) of the region of interest, x = [0, 2pi], y = [3.426*cos(3.426), 2pi*cos(2pi)].

[image]

So Q_N is the volume divided by N times the sum of the function evaluated at the randomly generated points. Hence:

```
total = 0
while i < N:
    x = random.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi)
    total += f(x)
    i += 1


area_of_rectangle = (2*np.pi)*(2*np.pi*np.cos(2*np.pi)-3.426 * np.cos(3.426))
area = (area_of_rectangle * total) / N
```

This code yielded an average result of 0.0603 for 1000 runs with N=1000 (to remove the influence of randomly generated values). As you increase N the accuracy increases.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track!

A couple pointers to put you on course...

- Make your bounding box bigger in the y dimension to alleviate some of the confusing math.  Yes, it will converge faster if you get it to "just touch" the max and min, but don't shoot for that yet.  Heck, just make it -5 < y < 10 and you will have a nice (larger) box that covers the area you want to integrate.  So, change your y generation to that and also change the area of your box calculation
- Don't change x, you have it right 0 < x < 2*pi
- When you are comparing the point to see if it is "under the curve" you do NOT need to check the x value... right?  Just check if y is between f(x) and the axis.  More on this in next point....  if so, it is "red"
- Also on the point above, you will also need another category for the points that are BELOW the x-axis, because you will want to reduce your total by that amount.  An alternate "trick" is to shift your whole function up by some constant such that the entire integral is positive, and then reduce your total by the size of that rectangle (constant * width)
- Also, as you work on this, plot your points with matplotlib, it should be very easy the way you have your points gathered to overlay scatter plots with what you have and see if it looks visually accurate!

Comment me back w/ further q's...  you got this!